# Android сохранение строк в xml

Tags: xml, android, строки

храню буквы в xml в таком виде

```
<string-array name="alphabet">
    <item>x</item>
    <item>y</item>
    <item>0</item>
    <item>1</item>
    <item> </item>
</string-array>
```

но когда загружаю  в коде то пробел превращается в пустую строку...

```
final String[] Array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.alphabet);
```

тоесть есть все симоволы кроме проблема, как его сохранить правильно или загрузить? 
Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте \u0020 или &#160; вместо пробела.